# Django template tags in javascript

Tags: django

Display javascript tag inside django template. I want to add this code 
`code =  "images/" + item.student__stud_lname + "_" + item.bcode + ".png"`

inside the 
 `<td><img src="{% static "+'code'+"  %}"</td>`

**UPDATED ANSWER:** 
`<td><img src="{% static "images/" %}' +code +'  "</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `code` to the context that you pass to your template, then do this

`<td><img src="{{code}}"</td>`

Comment: I'm calling my image tag inside js

Comment: add a `<script>var yourImage={{code}}</script>`  on your html template and call the variable on the JS

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in the template, you can just concatenate the strings:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/' %}{{ item.student__stud_lname }}_{{ item.bcode }}.png">
```

except I'm not sure what `item.student__stud_lname` is supposed to do, if you're trying to access related object attributes, use dot notation: `item.student.stud_lname`, assuming `student` is a foreign key on `item`.

Comment: `item.student__stud_lname` is a variable to be from views to ajax. I'm calling this to show inside my template with ajax call on top of it.

Comment: Ok. It’s just unusual to have a double underscore in a variable name. It’s going to cause issues if it’s a field on a model.